# NSDictionary in NSArray search

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, uisearchbar

I'm having a problem with some search code. I have an NSMutableArray, called `searchedData`, that contains NSDictionaries (one per object). Here's the search code I have now:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [tableData removeAllObjects]; // remove all data that belongs to previous search
    if([searchText isEqualToString:@""]||searchText==nil) {
        [tableView reloadData];
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (i < [dataSource count]) {
        NSDictionary *coolDict = [searchedData objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * title = [coolDict objectForKey:@"TITLE"];
        NSString * authorString = [coolDict objectForKey:@"AUTHOR"];

        NSRange titleRange = [[title lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];
        NSRange authorRange = [[authorString lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];

        if (titleRange.location != NSNotFound || authorRange.location != NSNotFound)
            [tableData addObject:title];
        i++;
    }

    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

It finds the number of entries, then goes to each entry, finds the objects for keys "TITLE" and "AUTHOR", and then displays entries in the UITableView if there is a match.

The problem is that it never displays anything, even if there is a match.
I know the table / dictionaries are not null (I have NSLogged it) so I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Why is it that your `while` loop loops for each `datasource` but pulls values from `searchedData` instead? Was that a typo or do those two mirror each other?

Comment: They don't mirror each other but they contain the same amount of objects.

Comment: BTW, you're gonna have a bit of a problem if an event occurs when the author and the book's title are the same, in your -tableView:didSelectRow: method

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to reload the tableView having added the relevant data to the datasource.

I have improved the coding of the method a bit, and added the missing line.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [tableData removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search
    if (![searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText != nil) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < [dataSource count]) {
            NSDictionary *coolDict = [searchedData objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString * title = [coolDict objectForKey:@"TITLE"];
            NSString * authorString = [coolDict objectForKey:@"AUTHOR"];

            NSRange titleRange = [[title lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];
            NSRange authorRange = [[authorString lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];

            if(titleRange.location != NSNotFound || authorRange.location != NSNotFound)
                [tableData addObject:title];
            i++;
        }
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include this but I already had [tableView reloadData];. Thanks